# Bitshares API - Create an account under a registrar using PHP

Tags: php, api

I've been trying to create an account under a registrar account on Bitshares Test Net programatically using Graphene API and its blockchain. I read the API documentation and have concluded that the PHP code bellow is what I need to execute to be able to create a new account.

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://testnet.bitshares.eu/';
$array = array(
    'jsonrpc'   => '2.0',
    'method'    => 'register_account',
    'params'    => array(
        'name'              => 'NEW_ACCOUNT_NAME',
        'owner_key'         => 'OWNER_KEY',
        'active_key'        => 'ACTIVE_KEY',
        'registrar_account' => 'REGISTRAR_ACCOUNT',
        'referrer_account'  => 'REGISTRAR_ACCOUNT',
        'referrer_percent'  => 1,
        'broadcast'         => 1
    ),
    'id'        => 1
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'GraphenePHP/1.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($array));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

The code above is not working. Also I am not getting any response. I have a feeling that I am missing something or the value of $url is incorrect.

Please help?

Comment: I have the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This Bitshares testnet link **https://testnet.bitshares.eu/** sometimes does not work.
You can simply use real net or install testnet on your side for this.